# Lint error duplicate keys when setting style

Tags: javascript

How can I avoid having duplicate keys or nested ternarys when setting my style? I need to change the margin for ios and certain iPhones.

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

const devices = ['iPhone 12', 'iPhone 12 Pro', 'iPhone 12 Pro Max'];

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingTop: 10,
    marginBottom: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 10 : 0;,
    marginBottom: devices.includes(DeviceInfo.getModel()) ? 30 : 0
  },
```

Comment: What's the problem with nested ternaries?

Comment: LInter doesnt allow it

Comment: Well it probably warns you about this for a reason - because with the code as shown, you could _never_ get a marginBottom of `10`, even if the device platform was iOS - because the next line would always overwrite it with either `30` or `0`.

Comment: Please show enough code for it to be valid code (code doesn't start with a property name), and what the version of the code is where the linter complains. Focus your question on the linter-warning issue, because a chained ternary would be the natural way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this.
`marginBottom: (Platform.OS === "ios" && 10) || (devices.includes(DeviceInfo.getModel() && 30 ) || 0;`

It may not perfectly fit what you want, but with a little modification it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your linter does not allow the use of a nested [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator, you can define a variable holding the data:

Since the value will always be `0` for non-ios, `30` if included in `devices` and `10` otherwise, your logic can look something like:

```
let iosMarginBottom = 0;
if (Platform.OS === "ios" ) {
    iosMarginBottom = (devices.includes(DeviceInfo.getModel() ? 30 : 10);
}
const style = {
    marginBottom: iosMarginBottom;
}
```